# How to choose database between MongoDB and Cassandra

Tags: mysql, mongodb, cassandra, database, nosql

Now I want to design a database, and there will be some tables within some dynamic attributes. I can choose a traditional RDBMS like MySQL to implement them with the EAV design model. But now I want to try some thing new. I heard that NoSQL database can solve the dynamic attributes problem in an easy way, and I want to choose one between MongoDB and Cassandra.

And here's some situations about the database I want to design:

There will be about 200,000 items in this database and the database will be store in a single server.

When a user want to use this database, the main procedure is that: the user would first visit table A, the a foreign key of table B, then visit table B, get a foreign key of table C. Table C has lots of fixed attributes and some dynamic attributes. Then the user will get a tuple from table C, read some values and then modify some values of this tuple, and may add some dynamic values of this tuple.

I would import almost all of this tuples from an Excel spreadsheet into my database in Java. So which one has a better support for Java?

After I import these data, there won't be any more insert or delete operations. Almost all of the operations for outside users are read and update. So which database is better for this scenario.

I know it's not necessary to use a NoSQL database in this small project, but I really want to try and learn one recently. So thanks for your answers, and if you have another options for me, it would be very great.

Comment: It's really hard to give a good answer, "better support" is very subjective. The real issue that you need to work out is which DB best fits your storage requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no obvious answer given the information you provided.

You described query patterns in terms of tables, joins, foreign keys. At first, I'd advice to think if it is possible to do data embedding, rather than referencing as between tables.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

For our project early stage we've chosen mongodb and despite we're moving some things to Cassandra now, I really don't regret about making this choice.

Mongo is really simple, flexible. Very easy for development, applying schema changes, querying. It forgives a lot. I'd say it is nearly priceless for NoSQL newcomers.

Cassandra is much more advanced. It requires more thinking about schema design and query patterns. Horizontal scalability is one of the best in NoSQL market. Cassandra has a big advantage in write operations as well.

Many Mongodb users come two Cassandra then. But only in case there are real performance and scalability reasons

But since you are going to have single-machine installation - mongodb might be enough. It has a very good read-performance while data fits the RAM.

Both of these databases have well-supported drivers.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver

For Cassandra it's worth referring to new Datastax driver

https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

> I know it's not necessary to use a NoSQL database in this small
>   project, but I really want to try and learn one recently.

I'd recommend Mongodb then...

Comment: Thanks! This is what I want. I think I can just use MongoDB to build the database because the main purpose now is to import all of these data in it and update some tuples. As the database structure is not very complex, I can move to Cassandra if we really need very high performance and scalability.